# Page layout navigator

Tags: page-layout, appexchange, app

I am curious is there an app that can navigate through fields and give detail meaning on each field. I kinda need this for new people who are working on Salesforce to help them better understand the platform and the associated fields .

Thanks,

Darko

Answer (score 0):

There is a possibility to check the field parameters in page layout edit mode without any external apps (natively). Just move your mouse cursor to the field label and you will get a summary text about this field:

[image]

Comment: Thanks @mast0r for the fast reply but this is not what i am thinking off. I am thinking of a tool app where I have a new person to salesforce. When he logs with his username he gets popup windows similar to those that salesforce offer at the beginning when you log in for the first time to salesforce. Similar to those but for page layouts where he can just press next and have detail explaining for every field.

Thanks,
Darko